# Why haven't Ukraine and Russia declared war?

Tags: international-relations, russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

Ukraine and Russia have technically [been at war since 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russo-Ukrainian_War) but neither has declared war publicly.

**What's the reason not to declare war if it even mentioned in the Wikipedia?**

Comment: Would there be any benefits to be officially *at war*? I can't think of any.

Comment: The distinction you are making between "technically" at war and "declared war publically" is not clear. "At war" is both a legal and a practical concept, but it is never secret. (E.g. the two Koreas are still technically and legally at war). If they are technically at war then they are publicly at war. Do you mean to ask why the war hasn't turned hot?

Comment: If anyone is new to the conflict then I just want to say that there also is a huge information war about winning the narrative. I would say that is also why the linked wikipedia article is so extensive. The first casualty when war comes is truth

Comment: @PaulJohnson The war has been hot for quite a while (just ask people who live near the border... or the relatives of people who flew over on MH17.) I think the question is more asking why they haven't officially declared war, even though they are _de factor_ at war.

Comment: @Frank that would be a continuation of Stalin's (and Lenin's) view on Ukrainian ethnicity and independence.

Answer (score 17):

I think the main reason is probably because, if it's an "irregular war," other nations with interests, agreements or obligations with either or both parties can pretend nothing, really, is going on.

If a formal, internationally official war is declared, then nations and groups of nations would be more likely to act, either on their own, or by being pushed into it by formal agreements, conventions or obligations.

Not declaring war gives both parties an "out" to back down or de-escalate if things are looking like they are moving in a direction they don't like. An actual war gives less options.

The United States has pretty much been in a constant state of war for the past 70 years or so, including a pre-emptive invasion, conquering and occupation of Iraq, and yet, they haven't been "officially" at war since WWII.

I'm not sure that a formal declaration has much meaning in a modern context.

Comment: People and states are so informal nowadays...

Answer (score 9):

From the Ukraine side:

- official declaring war on Russia would rapidly end in Ukrainian defeat - as long as there would be no limits for using army power. Just because current proxy-war would lose word "proxy" and became full-conventional war.
- Ukrainian economics is [critically](https://tradingeconomics.com/ukraine/imports/russia) dependent from Russian - in both import and export.

From the Russian side:

- It is a proxy-war, like US war in Syria, or like today's war in Lybia between [Turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_military_intervention_in_the_Second_Libyan_Civil_War) and [Egypt](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/africa/libyan-speaker-meets-haftar-in-egypt/1867550) + [France](https://www.politico.eu/article/libya-khalifa-haftar-in-retreat-france-hedges-its-bets/) + [Greece](https://thearabweekly.com/libyas-haftar-greece-strengthens-ties-athens) (NATO countries are on different sides of armed conflict, yes). In fact, there is a [LIST of Proxy Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_proxy_wars) Proxy war do not requires official declaration. Just for what? There are no regular army involved - so no casualties. At least now, People's Republics militia is doing well.
- Official war declaring would lead to the collapse of the Ukraine - which is already in agony. For now, it is IMF and US who are spending resources for that territory, and if the ukraine would collapse because of war - that burden would be on Russia. For what?

Comment: Also do not forget that Russia like would be further isolated diplomatically by officially declaring war. While current excuses for the presence of russian soldiers are pretty lame, a lame excuse is diplomatically still better than officially declaring war

Comment: Mmmmmm, no. 1)There are NO regular russian soldiers - just because OSCE would create a diplomatic scandal as it is monitoring border. And they are in no need their - as People Republics militia is doing well. 2)For now, situation is shown off, the West showed its real attitude to Russia, so no, that is not the point. In fact, Putin is very soft to the West - from my point of view, there is noone to talk with, and no things to talk about. At least to the west from Germany.

Comment: Well...by strict definition there are no regular soldiers in Ukraine as they are not identifying themselves as regular russian soldiers. But what is a soldier "fighting in Ukraine while on vacation" other than a lame excuse for a regular soldier?

Comment: Where did you pick that? On "proved source" as Bellingcat? There is no regular army - it is too easy to prove. Volonteers - yes, but for now even they are in no need - because front is stable. But if you so sure in that - how wold you explain, that ALL people changed during captive changes between Donetsk and Ukraine are with Ukrainian citizenship?))))))) In fact, here is just nothing to talk about

Comment: A lot of strong assertions in this answer are not backed on any sources. France and Greece current involvment in Libya ? Absence of Russian soldiers in Eastern Ukrain ? Concern in Kremlin for Ukrain's economy ? In any case, the parallel between the East Ukrain war and Syria or Lybia is false: US and Russian have no territorial claims in Syria, Egypt and Turkey have no territorial claims in Lybia. Russia's actions in Crimea and Donbass are expansionnist moves, and hardly by proxy.

Comment: @Evargalo, easy: 1)Libya: https://www.politico.eu/article/libya-khalifa-haftar-in-retreat-france-hedges-its-bets/ 2)Absence - no absence 3)Ukrainian civial war IS similar to Syrian. 4)Crimea and Donbass are two different cases - picking back Crimea and supporting Donbass are different points. In fact, all western claims and cries about that can be stopped by just two words: Yugoslavia, Kosovo. The west should be silent after that

Comment: There is even a wikipedia article on those extremely good equiped "volounteers": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_green_men_(Russo-Ukrainian_War) The is also various articles on the web regarding this, e.g. https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/438kv3/russian-soldiers-have-given-up-pretending-they-are-not-fighting-in-ukraine "Rebel leader Alexander Zakharchenko even admitted around the same time that active-duty Russian troops were fighting with his men, though he claimed that they had chosen to fight while on vacation."

Comment: Taking back Crimea from Ukraine? It's hard to do that when Kievan Rus' is the ancestor of Russia.  That would be like the US taking back Britain. Perhaps Ukraine should "take back" Moscow. That would be more logical.

Comment: You are continuing?) Kievan Rus owned Crimea? The Ukraine ever consisted in such borders as now? No - all that were gifts from the Soviet Union. Now it is time to return them. Also, it would be historically correct to return western ukraine to Poland and Hungary. So, yes, there should be some place around Kiev, which would be called "ukraine"

Comment: So, @Obie2.0, you don't have anything to answer, do you?) I appretiate your -1 - as it proves that answer is good and appropriate, but seems, that you don't have any arguments

Comment: No, but the successor states of Kievan Rus' did control Moscow. It was part of the Vladimir-Suzdal Principality. So Moscow is historically Ukrainian and must be returned. Don't worry, Putin can move to Sochi.

Comment: Now, with Crimea, Kievan Rus' touched it. but it did not actually control it, right? But the Byzantine Empire did. So maybe Turkey should take back Crimea. Or Italy, depending on whom you view as the legitimate succesor to the Roman Empire.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109819/discussion-between-user2501323-and-obie-2-0).

Comment: @Obie2.0 [The Russian Empire took control of Crimea in 1783](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimea#Russian_Empire_(1783%E2%80%931917)).  Crimea came under Ukrainian control only in 1954 by [an administrative action of the Soviet Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1954_transfer_of_Crimea).  Russia does have significant historical ties to Crimea, arguably much more significant than Ukrainian ties. IMO Russia's ties were not ample justification for an invasion and forceful annexation, but Putin apparently didn't agree with me.

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is that the practice of declaring war is no longer regarded as necessary; and as the other answers mention, it may provoke the other party, or force other countries to get involved.

Wikipedia's article on [declaring war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_of_war) states:

> Since 1945, developments in international law such as the United Nations Charter, which prohibits both the threat and the use of force in international conflicts, have made declarations of war largely obsolete in international relations.

And indeed, the list in that article of declarations of war since 1945 is very short - just 15, of which 4 are still in force (Syria, Iraq & Lebanon vs Israel (1948); Egypt vs Islamic State (2015)).

Notable among the absences from that list are the Korean War and Vietnam War - and the conflict in Ukraine.

Comment: I don't understand the quote. The United Nations Charter prohibits force in conflicts and that's why you don't need to declare war in order to attack somebody or defend against somebody?  That doesn't make much sense to me as such. Sounds a bit like "it just got out of fashion".